# Generalization of Cramer Rao Lower Bound.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Let $B(p)$ be a Bernoulli R.V. with mean $p$. Using the Cramer-Rao lower bound we have that for every unbiased estimator $\hat{\theta}$ of the parameter $p$ it holds

$$
E[(\hat{\theta}_n - p)^2] = Var[\hat{\theta}_n] \geq \frac{p (1-p)}{n}
$$

Let now $\hat{\theta}$ be an estimator such that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} E[ (\hat{\theta}_n - p)^2] = 0.  \qquad    (1)
\end{equation}

Can we show a (Cramer-Rao style) lower bound for the error of these estimators?
I would even be happy with a statement such as:

Let $\hat{\theta}$ be an estimator of $p$ such that (1) holds for all $p \in (0,1)$. Then 
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} n E[(\hat{\theta}_n - p)^2] > 0.
$$
This would mean that the rate of convergence of all such estimators is greater than $C/n$ for a constant $C$.